# Use starts with filter for a field in Share Point search

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to search in share point site using the url

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'C')

But getting a

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "invalidRequest",
> "message": "Cannot enumerate sites",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2023-06-22T09:41:39",
> "request-id": "101e303a-f611-4ec4-8536-f88555d49c68",
> "client-request-id": "101e303a-f611-4ec4-8536-f88555d49c68"
> }
> }
> }

Is there any way to use startswith in search

I am expecting to get the results with displayName starts with 'C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only search across a SharePoint tenant for sites that match keywords provided. It searches across multiple properties.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=c*
```

Probably additional filtering on the client is necessary. I would return id and displayName for all sites and filter the sites on the client.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*&$select=displayName,id
```

Comment: Is there a documentation where wild cards like "*" are mentioned

Comment: @MuhammedYaseen Graph API [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) has example with {query} which is not useful at all. I went through the related [discussion](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22f94e77f3-c166-cc46-de80-b4ca5e8e2803%22&in=body) some time ago and only wildcard * worked for me.